# unable to add 2 buttons in flutter under build widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am just trying to add 2 buttons in this ui:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('VIDEOCALL'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          height: 400,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                      child: TextField(
                    controller: _channelController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      errorText:
                          _validateError ? 'Channel name is mandatory' : null,
                      border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1),
                      ),
                      hintText: 'ENTER ENTRY CODE',
                    ),
                  ))
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: onJoin,
                        child: Text('Join'),
                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

but I am unable to add it.
sometimes I have a child already defines error or even if the code is accepted it does not pop on the screen.

Comment: well i said i tried everything , but i didnt restart my system.
seems that just restarting the system fixed the issue and now i can use the code
new RaisedButton.... and it just works as it should .

Answer (score 0):

well i said i tried everything , but i didnt restart my system.
seems that just restarting the system fixed the issue and now i can use the code
new RaisedButton.... and it just works as it should

```
Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: onJoin1,
                        child: Text('Join'),
                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: onJoin1,
                        child: Text('Join'),
                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```